# Как реализовать автоматическое создание новых объектов?

Tags: java

Допустим я создаю объект, объект имеет поля, которые я заполняю с помощью пользовательского ввода. Далее я сохраняю объект в файл. Проблема в том, что я не знаю, сколько именно мне понадобится объектов и поэтому хочу как-то реализовать автоматическое их создание, но не могу понять как. Возможно с помощью цикла как-то можно, но как потом эти объекты сериализовать?
UPD:
я разобрался с основной частью вопроса. Создаю объекты в цикле и добавляю в лист.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < countStudents; i++) {
         Student newStudent = new Student();
         list.add(newStudent);
         newStudent.text();
}
```

Далее я могу сохранять объекты в файл, все работает.

```java
try {
                FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("Base.ser");
                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    os.writeObject(list.get(i));
                }
                os.close();
                System.out.println("Данные сохранены!");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Но возникла другая проблема, как мне добавлять в текущий файл новые объекты? т.е. при перезапуске я могу считать данные которые внес до этого, а если хочу внести новые, то предыдущие стираются. На что стоит обратить внимание?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Какой смысл в автоматическом создании объектов, если их поля заполняет пользователь?  Если заранее неизвестно, сколько будет объектов, можно использовать список.  Если пользователь как-то задает количество объектов, можно создать и заполнить их массив.  Затем останется сериализовать список/массив объектов.

Comment: Вы сделали код сохранения объектов в файл. Вам нужно добавить обратный код - считывание объектов из файла.

Comment: Я сделал такой код, он считывает ранее введенную информацию. Просто если я хочу внести еще запись, предыдущие записи теряются. Как мне реализовать сохранение , чтобы данные просто добавлялись к уже имеющимся, а не записывались поверх?